# Linking UK biobank patient IDs with their corresponding genetic data

Tags: r, statistics, plink, phylogenetics, epidemiology

I am analyzing ukbb data and I have patient IDs for both cases and controls. Now I want the genetic data of all patients based on their IDs.
I am trying to test with chromosome 5 as I have both bgen and sample file. I am using plink 2 for the conversion of bgen and sample file
`plink2 --bgen ukb_chr5_v3.bgen ref-first --sample ukb22828_c5_b0_v3_s487239.sample --make-bed --out testfile`

I am getting three files as output like .pgen .psam .pvar.
This is how .psam looks like,

| FID | IID | sex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 482828 | 482282 | 1 |

and .pvar file has five columns, chromosome, position, ID, ref allele, alt allele.
I am still confused which IDs have the corresponding alleles/genotypes.
Please guide me in further analysis. My goal is find genetic data of specfic IDs which I am looking for.
Thanks

Comment: The genotypes are in the ``.pgen`` file, but encoded as a binary, so you can't query it directly. What are you going to do with the genotypes?

Comment: My aim is to calculate polygenic risk scores using pre-calculated weights for each individual and for that I possibly need effect allele count (0,1, or 2)